# Arrays in java using different methods

Tags: java, arrays

I have 3 different questions/requirements. I have attempted them all, but I feel very lost and not sure what's wrong with my code. I will first include the requirement and then put my code. Any help is appreciated!

1.Write a class/static method that takes an array of doubles as a parameter and returns the sum of all of the elements in the array.

```
public static void mystery(int[] a);
 for (int i = 0; i < a.length - 1; i++);
    if (a[i] < a[i + 1]);
        a[i] = a[i + 1];
}
```

2.Write a class/static method that takes an array of int as a parameter and returns an array of type boolean of the same length as the parameter. For each element in the parameter array for which the value is odd the returned array should have a true value for the corresponding element in its array. Likewise, even valued elements in the parameter array should be matched by corresponding false values in the returned array.

```
public class Practice
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int[] myArray = {1, 2, 3, 4};
        array(myArray);
        for(int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++)
            System.out.println(myArray[i]);
    } 
    public static void array(int[] a) {

        int n = a.length;
        int zero = a[0];
        a[0] = a[n-1];
        a[n-1] = zero;
    }
}
```

3.Write a class/static method that takes an array of Strings as a parameter and returns an array of Strings of the same length as the original array. The string in each element of the returned array will be reversed from the original string in the original array. So, if s[1]="the", then r[1]="eht".

```
public class Homework6  {
public static void Main()  {
    Array myArray=Array.CreateInstance( typeof(String), 9 );
    myArray.SetValue( "The", 0 );
    myArray.SetValue( "green", 1 );
    myArray.SetValue( "bag", 2 );
    Console.WriteLine( "The Array initially contains the following values:" );
    PrintIndexAndValues( myArray );
    Array.Reverse( myArray );
    Console.WriteLine( "After reversing:" );
    PrintIndexAndValues( myArray );
}
public static void PrintIndexAndValues( Array myArray )  {
    for ( int i = myArray.GetLowerBound(0); i <= myArray.GetUpperBound(0); i++ )
        System.out.println( "\t[{0}]:\t{1}", i, myArray.GetValue( i ) );
}
}
```

Comment: Please format your code using the format button. I read as far as the first requirement, which asks for an array of `double`; your method takes an `int[]`. Then I hit the large blocks of unformatted code and gave up.

Comment: Also, you shouldn't be putting ';' characters after the conditions in for-loops and if statements.

Comment: In all three cases you haven't done what's been asked of you. Pay attention to the parameter types and to the return types.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, this is clearly homework so I'm only going to provide hints - the entire point is for you to figure this out. Here's some help :-)

> 1. Write a class/static method that takes an array of doubles as a parameter and returns the sum of all of the elements in the array.

For this, you show a method signature `public static void mystery(int[] a)`. Here are a few hints:

1. does this take an array of doubles?
2. if you calculate a sum of a bunch of doubles, what data type would the result be? e.g. `mydouble1 + mydouble2 + mydouble3 == ????` Your method signature claims the return type is `void`, but that's not the data type I would expect from this addition of doubles, would you?
3. The code you showed is trying to store the sum inside an array. Seems like it would make more sense to create a new variable inside the method called sum, store the result inside this new variable, and then return that variable
4. Try **very** hard to avoid putting a semicolon after an if statement at this point in your coding experience. Specifically, the semicolon here can cause you a ton of problems, so remove it: `if (a[i] < a[i + 1]);`

> 2.Write a class/static method that takes an array of int as a parameter and returns an array of type boolean of the same length as the parameter.

You've defined a method `public static void array(int[] a)` to accomplish this. Some hints:

1. the requirement is to return an array of boolean. You're returning a `void`. This is the same mistake you make in the first problem - perhaps review how method signatures look in java, specifically how you define the type of the return value
2. your code here is not remotely doing what the requirement asks, looks like this is leftover code from somewhere else. Start by figuring out what return type you need for an array of booleans, and then create an empty boolean array, then try to figure out how to fill in that array of boolean from the array of integers you get passes

> 3.Write a class/static method that takes an array of Strings as a parameter and returns an array of Strings of the same length as the original array.

1. Ok, you definitely don't yet know how to define an array of strings in java. Google "java string array" and read the first result. Try to first write a method signature (e.g. just the `public return_stuff my_method_name(input_stuff my_argument)`) first that properly replaces `return_stuff` and `input_stuff` what a java string array

EDIT: making this a community wiki so others can update as OP changes their code problem. Feel free to contribute, but try to remember OP is clearly working out the *basics* of this problem, he/she probably doesn't need to understand coding conventions until at least lesson 2 :-)

Comment: All good points. There's also the OPs unnatural love of semi-colons.